# double numbers are not too accurate

Tags: java, variables, double, calculus

I've wrote a method for polynomial long division. And it works perfect with "good" polynomials. Under "good" I mean coefficients that divides accurate. Today I've faced with issue when tried to divide `2*x^3-18*x^2+.... / 7.00000(much zeros)0000028*x^2 + 5*x + ..`. After division `2*x^3 / 7.000...000028*x^2` I got `0.285714....53*x`. On next step we need to multiply `0.2857....53*x` on `7.00000...0000028*x^2 + 5*x + ..` and subtract it from dividend polynomial `2*x^3-18*x^2+...` and get new polynomial with degree = 2. But because of problem with `double` type I actually got polynomial `2.220....E-16*x^3 - 6*x^2 + ...`. I know that it is in fact zero near the `x^3`. I do not want to invent smth new and strange, that is why I am asking how to resolve it beautifully and correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Yes they are in accurate, floats too . You want answers , try reading how floats are encoded in your programming language.

Comment: You can always try something like https://gmplib.org/manual/Floating_002dpoint-Functions.html if you need more precision than normal double offers.

Comment: @MaazRehman and how it will help me?

Comment: @Paladin it is too complex solution for my case. I am looking for smth more simple

Comment: use BigDecimal.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many division results such as 1/7 cannot be represented exactly in either double or BigDecimal. If you go with BigDecimal you would have to pick a number of digits to preserve, and deal with rounding error. For double, you get more convenient arithmetic, but a fixed number of significant bits.

You have two options.

One is to handle rounding error. When a result is very close to zero, so close that it is probably due to rounding error, treat it as zero. I don't know whether that will work for your algorithm or not. If you go this way, you can use either double or BigDecimal.

The second option is to use a rational number package. In rational number arithmetic all division results can be represented exactly. 1/7 remains 1/7, without being rounded to a terminating decimal or binary fraction. If you go this way, search for "java rational number" (no quotes) and decide which one you like best.